# Pixate Freestyle Android / iOS still in active development?

Tags: android, pixate

I would like to use your Pixate-Freestyle-Android library in my app.
But I am currently at the limit of the product.

Because I need this library to handle different widget that are not currently stylable :
- viewpager
- seekbar or progressbar
- TabLayout
- SearchView
- Webview

And the support of custom font and "@import" would be amazing.

I would like to know if Pixate Freestyle Android / iOS still in active development ?

Comment: "our" library? I did not even know that stack overflow has its own Android library project :) I have the feeling this is beyond the scope of SO, even if it is about software.

Answer (score 1):

The last commit in GitHub is from two years ago.

http://www.pixate.com

It says that Google has acquired Pixate.